# How can I prevent crumbs from coming off an interior plaster-like wall?

Tags: walls, painting, texture

I recently moved into a house and I want to fix the interior walls. They are covered in a material that I never even saw before, so I would like to replace/cover with something, but I am confused over the options.

The house is in France, Brittany region, so it's super humid here due to frequent raining and proximity to the ocean. Because of this, some neighbours suggested to not cover the walls with anything, as it allows them to "breathe" through this material. However, to me it just looks unfinished and I don't really like it. To add to my dislike, these walls tend to "shed" (as in small pieces of it fall on the ground every day) so I have a vacuum ready next to me. We will only be living here for a year, so I would appreciate some lower cost options, maybe. Please help, I am having a lot of trouble with translating certain materials as well, as I don't speak perfect French so I am in real need of advice.

[image]

Comment: Take the neighbors advice and leave it alone.  They are familiar with the climate and have experienced it.  Just put up with it for a year. Otherwise painting or covering may come back to bite you.

Comment: For just a year, cheap nice looking curtains to cover.  Still allows it to breath, but looks nicer.  The neighbours should be the best resource of information.  They live with those walls.

Comment: I don't have a useful answer, being unfamiliar with this wall strategy, but a good scrub with a nylon brush should dislodge enough of the crumbs that you can put the vacuum away, at least for a while. A breathable paint would also help seal the surface (if such a thing exists).

Comment: "We will only be living here for a year" - then you do nothing (except maybe 'broom' it +1. or shop vac with the fuzzy stick). Half the people who come to see the showing are going to ask *who the hell painted the brick??!?! NEXT.*